# Скрипт поиска по сайту

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

http://htmlweb.ru/ajax/example/search.php делал все в точности как на сайте. Как сделать так что бы проверяло сколько записано в поисковой строчке и начинало поиск только тогда когда будет больше 3 символов в текстовом поле?

В теге head:

```
<script language="javascript" src="ajax_framework.js"></script>
```

В body:

```
<h2>Ajax Search Engine</h2>

<form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" method="post" action="javascript:insertTask();">
    <div class="searchInput">
    <input name="searchq" type="text" id="searchq" size="30" onkeyup="javascript:searchNameq()"/>
    <input type="button" name="submitSearch" id="submitSearch" value="Search" onclick="javascript:searchNameq()"/>
    </div>
</form>

<h3>Search Results</h3>
<div id="msg">Type something into the input field</div>
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

ajax_framework.js:

```
/* -------------------------- */
/*   XMLHTTPRequest Enable    */
/* -------------------------- */
function createObject() {
var request_type;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return request_type;
}

var http = createObject();

/* -------------------------- */
/*        SEARCH              */
/* -------------------------- */
function searchNameq() {
searchq = encodeURI(document.getElementById('searchq').value);
document.getElementById('msg').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Searching for <strong>" + searchq+"";
    // Set te random number to add to URL request
    nocache = Math.random();
    http.open('get', 'in-search.php?name='+searchq+'&nocache = '+nocache);
    http.onreadystatechange =  searchNameqReply;
    http.send(null);
    }
    function searchNameqReply() {
    if(http.readyState == 4){
    var response = http.responseText;
    document.getElementById('search-result').innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

Поиск в базе in-search.php:

```
include('config.php');
$searchq = $_GET['name'];
$getName = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE name LIKE "%'.addslashes($searchq).'%"');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getName))
    echo $row['name'] . '<br/>';
```

Comment: используйте sphinx быстрый и лёгкий поисковый движок

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В JS добавить проверку на длину строки поиска:

```
function searchNameq() {
    if(document.getElementById('searchq').value.length > 3){
        ....
    }
}
```

В PHP Добавить проверку на длину строки поиска:

```
if(strlen($_GET['name']) > 3 ){
    $searchq = $_GET['name'];
    $getName = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE name LIKE "%'.addslashes($searchq).'%"');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getName))
        echo $row['name'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Нужно выбрать только одно или надо и то и то?

Comment: Ну смотря где вы хотите делать проверку, по хорошему и там и там нужно проверять

Comment: Большое спасибо помогло! Можете еще с кое чем помочь?С этим же скриптом

Comment: Создавайте вопрос

Comment: Хорошо я вас ссылку скину, возможно вы тоже знаете ответ

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548359/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83-js-php-ajax-mysql