# Поиск по двум полям одновременно

Tags: php, mysql

http://htmlweb.ru/ajax/example/search.php делал все в точности как на сайте. Как сделать так что бы искало по имени и фамилии? Что-то подобное сделал но пока что ищет только ИЛИ по имени ИЛИ только по фамилии надо чтобы искало по имени и фамилии одновременно (Вася Пупкин и Пупкин Вася) вот мои наброски:

```html
<?
include('auth/bd.php');
$searchq = $_GET['name'];
$getName = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE "%'.addslashes($searchq).'%" OR lastname LIKE "%'.addslashes($searchq).'%"');
if(!empty($searchq))
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getName))
    echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'] . '<br/>';
?>
```

Comment: `OR` замените на `AND`.

Comment: @Visman Не помогло

Comment: А почему вы интересно одну и ту же переменную сравниваете с именем и фамилией?

Comment: @Visman а как тогда?

Comment: @BedOmar  $searchq у вас хранит full_name (Вася Пупкин),  или одно из них ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбиваем строку на 2 и ищем в таблицах

```html
<?
include('auth/bd.php');
$searchq = mb_strtolower($_GET['name']);
$nameArr = explode(" ", $searchq);//Разделяем входную строку на 2 по пробелу
if(count($nameArr) == 2){ //проверяем сколько слов было указано — если 2 то делаем запрос. Если 1, то нужно делать как у Вас было
$getName = mysql_query('
 SELECT * 
 FROM users 
 WHERE 
  firstname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($searchq)).'%" 
   OR lastname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($searchq)).'%" 
   OR (
    firstname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($nameArr[0])).'%" 
    AND lastname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($nameArr[1])).'%"
   )
');
}
if(!empty($searchq))
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getName))
    echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'] . '<br/>';
?>
```

Comment: код не безопасен.

Comment: Ну мы пока помогаем алгоритм написать а потом проверки уже делать

Comment: @Visman почему?

Comment: @Mihanik71, это неправильный подход, так как он получит свой ответ и уйдет, а кто-то еще применит это дырявое решение и у себя.

Comment: код то робочий но подскажите пожалуйсто какие дыры там есть? и как их исправить

Comment: @Mihanik71 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in W:\domains\localhost\in-search.php on line 5

Comment: @BedOmar поправил

Comment: @Mihanik71 mysql устарело расширение в php7 его удалили это рас, во вторых как может быть это рабочем кодом, если я напишу `Пупкин Вася` или `Вася Пупкин` он мне толком не найдёт ничего потому что в выдаче будут `Васильевы`,`Пупкины` и т.д. но не ВАСЯ ПУПКИН. Код не знает по крайней мере что вы напишите первым имя или фамилию, а может вообще просто имя или просто фамилию. Да и алгоритм хромает делаем `strtolower` не убедившись что там есть переменная, да и как то нелогично искать либо име или фамилию либо имя и фамилию.

Comment: @Mihanik71 теперь Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in W:\domains\localhost\auth\in-search.php on line 19

Answer (score 1):

Код а точнее sql будет работать при следующем раскладе.

Допустим  $searchq  = (Вася Пупкин или Пупкин Вася).

А колонки в таблице имеют следующие значения

firstname = (xxxВасяxxx) , lastname = (xxxПупкинxxx)

или

firstname = (xxxПупкинxxx) , lastname = (xxxВасяxxx)

```
include('auth/bd.php');
$searchq = $_GET['name'];
$searchq = addslashes($searchq);
$sql = "SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `users`
WHERE (
    `firstname` LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX('".$searchq."', ' ', 1),'%')
    AND `lastname` LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX('".$searchq."', ' ', - 1),'%')
  ) 
  OR (
    `firstname` LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX('".$searchq."', ' ', - 1),'%')
    AND `lastname` LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX('".$searchq."', ' ', 1),'%')
  )";
$getName = mysql_query($sql);
if(!empty($searchq))
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getName))
        echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'] . '<br/>';
```

Да и кстати не пользуясь функцией mysql_connect,mysql_query ...

Пользуйся [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Надеюсь помог.Удачи

Comment: код робочий, но у меня жывой поиск по этому мне надо что бы при вводе первых нескольких букв фамили у меня находило человека, с данным кодом человек находится только при вводе всех соответствующих символов, тоесть Пупкина найдет только тогда когда я введу Вася Пупкин, а мне нужно чтобы когда я введу "Пупк" нашло сразу всех пользователей с такой фамилие, если исправете код под мои "требования" выберу как наилучший ответ

Comment: @BedOmar Замени AND на OR

Comment: Мда лучше кастыля на mysql ничего не предумаешь

Answer (score -3):

Ну теперь не удержусь от ответа как организовать поиск:

```
 1. Устанавливаем sphinx и пишем конфигурационный фаил
 2. Запускаем его демон
 3. Интегрируемся с api
 4. Получаем результат...
```

Доки по сфинксу можно найти по ссылкке: http://sphinxsearch.com/

Более подробная инфа сдесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/104690/